# Python search engine error while accessing the code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code I am using.

```
from google import google

search_results = google.search("this is test", 3)
for result in search_results:
    print(result.description)
```

Now when I was trying to access it I was getting this error

```
 Error accessing: http://www.google.com/search?q=
```

What will be the problem?

EDIT: I am not asking the alternative, I just ask Why this problem occurs? What will be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use requests python library to search on google. Install requests by `pip install requests` You can use google to search anything and parse the result with `Beautifulsoup`. Following code search the query on google and after that `BeautifulSoup` is used to get the URLs that Google returned.

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = 'any search term'


r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(query))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    links.append(item.a['href'])

print(links)
```

Comment: Hi, Himanshu, I did the same earlier but my some seniors told me that it is not a good way to do this, they also told me that you should create a custom search engine to do this. :)

Comment: `from google import google` is a custom engine? What do you mean by a custom engine? Generally the main rule is not to reinvent the wheel. I think @Himanshu solution is good. Otherwise, specify what you need exactly.

Comment: Hi, @TomWojcik I mean from the google custom engine with the Google's API.  And you both guys didn't tell me Why this problem (above error) occurs.?